# How to check Bitcoin payments received or not

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am creating a software and i want to take anonymous payments through bitcoins and once the payment is received to my bitcoin address then the user get serial key of that software...

so How i can check bitcoin payment of specific amount is received or not using bitcoin #transaction id in vb.net app.

Comment: Note that when using the transaction-id you're vulnerable to malleability (and reduced privacy for you and your customers). Better generate a new address for each transaction and check that enough bitcoin was received on that address.

Comment: How to create new BTC address for each transaction? (i already check blockchain API but it showing some db errors and wont work as expected)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variety of third party services if you don't feel like running your own bitcoin node. Full disclosure: I work at BlockCypher, and am biased about recommending [BlockCypher's API](http://www.blockcypher.com/). In particular, we have an event notification service that [might fit your needs well.](http://dev.blockcypher.com/#events-and-hooks)

But if you don't want to use us, there are many others available, like [Chain](http://www.chain.com) and [Coinbase](http://www.coinbase.com/), for example.

If you don't trust a third party service, you can run [bitcoin-core](https://bitcoin.org/en/download) on your own infrastructure, or try another implementation, like [btcd](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd) or [Toshi](https://toshi.io/).

Please note, as mentioned by a comment above, there's a double-spend attack vector associated with transaction malleability, which makes instant confirmation difficult. There are risk mitigation strategies, like BlockCypher's [Confidence Factor](https://medium.com/blockcypher-blog/from-zero-to-hero-bitcoin-transactions-in-8-seconds-7c9edcb3b734) or using off-chain transactions within a single service (like Circle or Coinbase).